# ml-gradle NOT to create my-app-content database

Tags: ml-gradle

How do I modify the ml-gradle project so that it will NOT create the default "my-app-content" database?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the gradle.properties file,
set mlNoRestServer=true